# How to vertically align one column in a two-column grid system(materialize)

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am designing a two-column layout, where some texts sit on the left column and a big img sits on the right. I use `col s12 l6` so that on a smaller screen these two would stack together.

I want the left text to be vertically aligned in a large screen but perform normally in a smaller screen.
I am using Materialize.

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row" style="border:solid">
        <div class = "col s12 l6" style="border:solid">
            <p>I want to vertically align in my parent container in big screen,but perform normally when in small screen</p>
       </div>
    <div class = "col s12 l6" style="border:solid">
        <img src="https://comotion.uw.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/image.jpg" ></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want in big Screen:
[image: big screen]
I want in small screen:
[image: small creen]

[I am the example link](https://codepen.io/frostless/pen/YvBzbM)

Comment: You may want to use the [`valign-wrapper`](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html) and then use this workaround: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/3327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Solution (Flexbox)**

**HTML**

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row Aligner" style="border:solid">
        <div class="row Aligner-item--top"></div>
        <div class = "col s12 l6  Aligner-item" style="border:solid">
            <p>I want to vertically align in my parent container in big screen,but perform normally when in small screen</p>
       </div>
       <div class="row Aligner-item--bottom"></div>
    <div class = "col s12 l6" style="border:solid">
        <img src="https://comotion.uw.edu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/image.jpg" ></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
.Aligner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Aligner-item--top {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.Aligner-item--bottom {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
}
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/chrisbradshaw/pen/XYOdXL

1. Add a div with the class of "row Aligner-item--top" above and class "Aligner-item--bottom" below the target div.
2. Add class "Aligner" to parent div.
3. Set "Aligner" class to display:flex, align-items: center, and justify-content: center in CSS.
4. Add "align-self: flex-start;" to top div and "align-self: flex-bottom;" to bottom div.
5. Add media query so that this behavior is only implements on Viewports below 900px.

### **Original Solution (not optimal, "hard coding" margin-top):**

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .v-align {
    margin-top: 10vh;
  }
}
```

**Updated codepen:** https://codepen.io/chrisbradshaw/pen/bKzNMR

1. I added class "v-align" on the div containing the paragraph and applied margin-top of 10vh in the CSS to vertically center the text. You could also experiment with CSS Flexbox to get this more precise.
2. Based on feedback from Manoj Kumar, I added media query to the .v-align margin-top so that it would only be applied on Viewports larger than 900px. You can experiment with this to get it perfect.

Comment: Wasn't the column classes already the same? Nice it's another hack! :) But it would be better to give margin-top only for large screen media query.

Comment: Agree, the media query makes it better, updating the codepen/post.

Comment: Good strategy....using media query to tackle the big screen.Just the 10vh does not seem to perfectly align the text box? It seems to me that it would be hard to find the right value to tackle all cases(different size of text box?)

Comment: Okay I added a new Flexbox solution where it is perfectly aligned and will tackle different sizes of text box. :)